# Why the map of the pushout of the cone is taken from $X$ to $*$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, pushforward, cofibrations

Here is the pushout of the cone in some notes of Colorado Univ.:

> [image]

I am wondering why it looks like this, especially why we took $X$ to the base point *?
could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of a cone as a quotient $X \times [0,1]/(x,1) \sim (x',1)$?

Comment: Yes @G.Chiusole but I am more familiar with the one of Wikipedia ... where we mod out by $X \times \{1\}$

Comment: @G.Chiusole I think also we are in the based case .... so the definition will be a little bit different from what you stated .... am I correct?

Comment: Then by definition of the pushout, this construction gives you exactly that. $CX = X \times I \cup \{\ast\}/ (X,1) \sim \{\ast\}$.

Comment: Recall here that the pushout of topological spaces is given as the disjoint union of (in this case) $X \times I$ and $\{\ast\}$ and then identifying the images (in this case) $i_1(X) \subseteq X \times I$ and $p(X) = \{\ast\}$, where $p$ is the projection of $X$ onto a point.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are considering based topological spaces. The $\ast$ in the lower left position is not a base point of either space.

Comment: @G.Chiusole because the document is assuming that our spaces are based

Comment: The above pushout-construction does not work for based spaces.  In the based case you have to replace $X$ in the upper left corner by $X \times \{1\} \cup \{x_0\} \times I$ and $i_1$ by the inclusion. This results in the reduced cone $C(X,x_0)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost why I should do this?

Comment: For based spaces one works wit the reduced cone which is $C(X,x_0) = (X \times I) / (X \times \{1\} \cup \{x_0\} \times I)$. But clarify what the situation is in your notes.

Comment: In your third comment from below, why we did not mod out instead by $X \times \{1\} \cup \{ x \sim \{*\} \}$?

Comment: http://math.colorado.edu/~agbe5088/math6280/classnotes/Class7.pdf here is the file I am speaking about @PaulFrost